# JS code is not working, how to fix the error "Uncaught RuntimeError: indirect call to null"

Tags: javascript, function, null, webassembly, emscripten

I was compiling code via emscripten and got stuck. My project is using libGD. I compile with the command:

```
em++ ./main.cpp -lgd -o index.html
```

and when launching the page, the following error appears in the browser console:

```
Enter captcha. 127.0.0.1:1237:21
Uncaught RuntimeError: indirect call to null
createExportWrapper http://127.0.0.1/index.js:992
callMain http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4903
doRun http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4957
run http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4968
setTimeout handler*run http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4964
runCaller http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4888
removeRunDependency http://127.0.0.1/index.js:913
receiveInstance http://127.0.0.1/index.js:1080
receiveInstantiationResult http://127.0.0.1/index.js:1098
promise callback*createWasm/instantiateAsync/< http://127.0.0.1/index.js:1139
promise callback*instantiateAsync http://127.0.0.1/index.js:1131
createWasm http://127.0.0.1/index.js:1168
<anonymous> http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4430
index.wasm:38346:1
```

judging by "cout" wasm starts correctly, without errors. Something is wrong in JS. I tried to fix the error by appending ", true" to the function calls, but this resulted in a complete wasm file and the following error:

```
Aborted(Assertion failed: exported native function `main` not found) index.js:929:6
Uncaught RuntimeError: Aborted(Assertion failed: exported native function `main` not found)
abort http://127.0.0.1/index.js:948
assert http://127.0.0.1/index.js:472
createExportWrapper http://127.0.0.1/index.js:990
callMain http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4903
doRun http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4957
run http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4968
setTimeout handler*run http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4964
runCaller http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4888
removeRunDependency http://127.0.0.1/index.js:913
receiveInstance http://127.0.0.1/index.js:1080
receiveInstantiationResult http://127.0.0.1/index.js:1098
promise callback*createWasm/instantiateAsync/< http://127.0.0.1/index.js:1139
promise callback*instantiateAsync http://127.0.0.1/index.js:1131
createWasm http://127.0.0.1/index.js:1168
<anonymous> http://127.0.0.1/index.js:4430
index.js:948:11
```

Here is all project files that was created

```
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a17aveyfocxnr28/AABHLNjyqHCCJyZ3-dBkVp44a?dl=0
```

I'm not strong enough to solve this problem, where is the mistake?

Comment: #include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <gd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <emscripten.h>
using namespace std;int main()
{
int w, h;
w = atoi("15");
h = atoi("15");
FILE *stream;
gdImagePtr into, out;
EM_ASM(
stream = FS.open('image.bmp', 'w+');
);
        into = gdImageCreateFromBmp(stream);
        gdImageSetInterpolationMethod(into, GD_BILINEAR_FIXED);
        out = gdImageScale(into, w, h);
        gdImageBmp(out, stream, 90);
    cout << "Enter captcha.\n";

    return 0;
    }

Comment: so i change my cpp code(add emscripten.h include, add EM_ASM box, use FS.open in it) and now i havent got errors: